# create shell /batch Windows for comparing two text files?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, windows-server, system-administration

create shell / batch for comparing two text files and view the different line but does not take the space and tab in considertation.
I create this bat but displaying All lines ,i need juste diffrence lines.

```
FC /W /L /UNE /T /C /A try1.txt try2.txt
if errorlevel 0 if not errorlevel 1 goto egal
if errorlevel 1 if not errorlevel 2 goto diff
if errorlevel 2 if not errorlevel 3 goto err
:egal
echo:Les fichiers sont egaux
goto fin
:diff
echo:Les fichiers sont differents
goto fin
:err
echo:Une erreur s'est produite
goto fin
:fin
```

Comment: Please format your code as such by clicking the "Code Sample" `{}` button, by pressing *Ctrl+K* or by simply preceding each line by four *spaces*! And read at least the [tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how ths site works!

Comment: You can also try this HTA file that let you browse the two files to compare line by line with automatic recording if there is a difference between their lines  [File2Compare](http://vb.developpez.com/telecharger/detail/id/2348/File2Compare-Comparaison-de-deux-Fichiers-ligne-par-ligne)

Answer (score 0):

The Simplest and fastest method is using `findstr` command it will compare and return the result to new file.

```
 findstr /v /i /x /g:<source file> <target file> > outputfile

     /v : Prints only lines that do not contain a match.
     /i : Specifies that the search is not to be case-sensitive.
     /x : Prints lines that match exactly.
     /g: file : Gets search strings from the specified file
```

```dos
@echo off
Set "File1=File1.txt"
Set "File2=File2.txt"
Set "Log=CompareResult.txt"
findstr /vixg:%File1% %File2% >%Log%
Start "" %Log%
```

Comment: i need specification does not take the space and tab in consideration !

Answer (score 0):

```
if errorlevel 2 if not errorlevel 3 goto err
if errorlevel 1 if not errorlevel 2 goto diff
:egal
```

`errorlevel` must be tested in reverse order as it is interpreted as "if errorlevel is n or greater than n"

Hence, if errorlevel 0 is "go always" (there are esoteric circumstances where errorlevel may be set negative)

if 2 or more ... error
otherwise if 1 or more ... different
otherwise is same.

Comment: In general this is true, but there are also `if NOT errorlevel` conditions, so the order is in fact irrelevant...

Comment: @aschipfl : Absolutely true, on second look. The gating via the `not` makes something that could be done simply very complex. Seems OP has abandoned the question. It would appear that a difference report is required - but without an example of what this report should show, we're guessing. The `errorlevel` processing should be fine as-is, even if it's too complex.